# Jquery binding event to an element in a loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is executed on the callback of an Ajax call:

```
jQuery.each(res, function () 
{
 var element = $("<p id=\"" + this.UrlTitle +"\">" + this.Name + "</p>").live('click',function () { alert('hello from binded function call') });
  dataList.append(element);
});
```

"res" is just a JSON object which is well formed and i can see the p elements in my html well created too.

My issue is that when i click in a paragraph i get 3 alerts execution (the "res" elements has a length of 3), and its like the binding is done three times foreach p element.

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: And, in fact, `.live` is deprecated, as of jQuery 1.7 and higher ones. ) `.on` should be used instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `.live` on a DOM element (which is created from the HTML string in this case). `.live` only works with **selectors**. See the list of drawbacks in its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

I don't see a reason to use event delegation at all here, just bind the event handler directly to the element using `.on` or the shorthand `.click` (did some extra refactoring ;)):

```
jQuery.each(res, function () {
    $("<p/>", {
         id: this.UrlTitle,
         text: this.Name
     }).on('click', function () { 
         alert('hello from binded function call') 
    }).appendTo(dataList);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.live()` in a rather strange way. `.live()` can't be (correctly) used on just any old jQuery object. Use `.click()` or `.on()`:

```
$.each(res, function () 
{
 var element = $("<p id=\"" + this.UrlTitle +"\">" + this.Name + "</p>").on('click', function () { alert('hello from binded function call') });
  dataList.append(element);
});
```

---

#### However...

[There is a **far** nicer syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for creating jQuery objects with various attributes and event listeners:

```
$.each(res, function () 
{
    $("<p/>", {
        id: this.UrlTitle,
        text: this.Name,
        click: function () {
            alert('hello from binded function call')
        }
    ).appendTo(dataList);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on()` method instead of the `live()` method. I think what's happening is the event is being attached to a parent 3 times (`live()` uses event delegation) so each time a `p` is clicked it fires off the three attached handlers.

`on()` can use event delegation but internally works differently to `live()`

```
jQuery.each(res, function () 
{
 var element = $("<p id=\"" + this.UrlTitle +"\">" + this.Name + "</p>").on('click',function () { alert('hello from binded function call') });
  dataList.append(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .live() and not adding an onclick attribute or it shouldn't be in that loop.

Live acts like CSS and is bound even if an element is dynamically created on a page. If you use bind('click', ....) or on('click', ....) it won't work that way. It will need to be explicitly set on that element like you are doing here.

What you are doing is actually binding a new onclick event to EVERY element with #this.UrlTitle for each iteration of that loop.

That's why you are getting three alerts. Either use jQuery on() or bind() or set onclick as you do with your id ... onclick="alert('....');".